# How to travel through a complex JSON in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a complex JSON object and I'd like to travel through this JSON and add more property to them.

This is my example of the JSON object.

```
Object {root: Object}
      root: Object
          entity_children: Array[1]
              0: Object
                  entity_children: Array[1]
                     0: Object
                         entity_children: Array[10]
                            0: Object
                            1: Object
                            2: Object
                            3: Object
                         entity_id: "00145E5BB2641EE284F811A7907757A3"
                         entity_name: "Functional Areas"
                         entity_type: ""
    .....
```

So basically, I have the JSON object that have property "entity_id", "entity_name", "entity_type" and "entity_children".

"entity_children" may contain list of objects inside. How can I travel through this to every element. I already tried hasOwnProperty('entity_children') but it goes through only 1 level.

This is my Raw JSON

```
{"root":   
    {"entity_id":"00145E5BB8C21EE286A007464A64508C",
     "entity_name":"TP_GTPAPI_TEST_BASE_ACC",
     "entity_type":"",
     "entity_children":
          [{"entity_id":"00145E5BB8C21EE286A007464A66508C",
            "entity_name":"TEST_CATALOG_GTPAPI",
            "entity_type":"",
            "entity_children":
                [{"entity_id":"00145E5BB8C21EE286A007464A66708C",
                  "entity_name":"Functional Areas",
                  "entity_type":"",
                  "entity_children":
                         [{"entity_id":"00145E5BB8C21EE286A007464A66908C",
                ......
```

Please help.

Comment: Use recursion http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion

Comment: "This is my example of the JSON object." - could you paste in the raw JSON? I think that would be more readable than the representation you've put in.

Comment: use looping in javascript.

Comment: JSON is an acronym for `JavaScript Object Notation`, so a basic `for...in` (which is used to iterate objects) should do it, and as tommi said, perhaps recursion is what you need: `if (obj[i] instanceof Object) { loopFunction(obj[i])} else {;`

Comment: What do you want to do to this object?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you have children property in you object that is an array of the same type of object. Which makes it a hierarchical object. You will need both iteration and recursion to properly travel through all of your object.
Take a look at the following code that has both the iteration and recursion.
    var data = {
        root: {
            a: "1",
            b: "1",
            c: "1",
            d: [{
                a: "1.1",
                b: "1.1",
                c: "1.1",
                d: [{
                    a: "1.1.1",
                    b: "1.1.1",
                    c: "1.1.1",
                    d: [

```
                {
                    a: "1.1.1.1",
                    b: "1.1.1.1",
                    c: "1.1.1.1",
                    d: "1.1.1.1"
                }]


            }]
        }, {
            a: "1.2",
            b: "1.2",
            c: "1.2",
            d: "1.2"
        },

        ]
    }
};

function loop(obj) {
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (obj[i].d != null) {
            loop(obj[i].d);
            alert(obj[i].a);
        }
    }
}

function travel() {
    loop(data.root.d);
}
```

see [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SaTLL/2/)